# Java user input has to be in range / Produce integers by 10 for 20 lines

Tags: java, loops, boolean, conditional-statements

Need a couple things in my code. I've been looking at it for 8 hours straight and can't figure it out. I need for the user input to be between -459 and 212. If it's an integer out of the range, it'll print line to re-enter it then go ahead and convert them. Right now it's not doing either of those and just going through the code. Am I supposed to use a Boolean or a if when? No idea.

Second problem is when Fahrenheit and Celsius print out after the conversion, I need them to list 20 more lines with adding 10 to each temperature. Is this a count? Major help needed please!

What I have so far:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperatures {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double Fahrenheit;
    double Celsius;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
        Fahrenheit = scan.nextInt();

        if(Fahrenheit >= -459 && Fahrenheit <= 212)


            System.out.println("Please enter a number between -459 and 212 degrees:");
            Fahrenheit = scan.nextInt(); 

    Celsius = ((Fahrenheit -32)*5)/9;

    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    System.out.print("Fahrenheit:  " + Fahrenheit + "     Celsius:  " + fmt.format(Celsius));


}
}
```

Comment: Now it's coming up that my Fahrenheit and Celsius variable have not been initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` conditions are inverted. And the next `nextInt()` is not in the `if` block. If you want it to repeat until you get a valid input, you need to turn it into a `while` loop:

```
while(Fahrenheit < -459 || Fahrenheit > 212) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between -459 and 212 degrees:");
    Fahrenheit = scan.nextInt();
}
```

I didn't really understand the second question.

Comment: The second part is having the user input for Fahrenheit converted to Celsius and both temperatures print out on the same line, which I got. Then the assignment asks to start listing the temperatures in increments of 10 degrees. Then stop at 20 lines.